# Meteor package.js with includes

Tags: meteor, build-process

I am working on a new Meteor app that I want to structure as a set of packages.
For each package, package.js is used to specify what files to include for client and server. This is standard usage.

My question: I want to divide a package into features, and I'd like to describe each feature with a file on the same lines as what package.js does for packages.  The main function of the feature file is to list the files of that feature that are required on client and server; concretely the feature file will contain api.use() calls that logically are included in the parent package.js file. In other words, I'm looking for an 'include' functionality for package.js.

Is such a thing possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by generating the api.addFiles calls in the package.js. To do that I tweaked the npm meteor-package-paths module, in particular the js.coffee module to add the additional 'feature' layer of directories.